# Ransack eq_any for boolean values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ransack

I have a model that has a boolean field called `ignored`. What I did right up to this point is not display records which have this field set to true by having a `default_scope where(:ignored => false)`.

Now, in my Ransack search form I would like to have a checkbox named `Include ignored` so the table would also display the records which are ignored along with the ones which aren't.

I got as far as adding the checkbox to my search form `f.check_box(:ignored_eq)` but when checking this, the list will display ONLY the ignored records. How do I display records in all states when checking this box?

Controller:

```
def index
  @q = Venue.search(params[:q])
  @venues = @q.result.page(params[:page]).per_page(15)
end
```

Search form (HAML):

```
= search_form_for @q, url: [:admin, :venues]  do |f|
  = f.text_field :name_cont
  = f.text_field :locality_name_cont
  = f.text_field :categories_name_cont
  = f.check_box :ignored_eq
  = content_tag :button, type: :submit, class: 'btn' do
    = content_tag(:i, "", class: "icon-search")
    = t("helpers.links.search")
```

The desired functionality is: when I enter the page I want to have only the ones that have ignore = false listed and have the box unchecked. When I check the box and submit the form I want to have ignored as well as non-ignored ones displayed. Is this possible with Ransack?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use the [rewhere](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#rewhere) AR method.

and have something like that for the `ignored` flag:

```
def index
  @q = Venue.search(params[:q])
  @q = @q.rewhere("ignored = 0 OR ignored = 1") if params[:ignored_eq] == 1
  @venues = @q.result.page(params[:page]).per_page(15)
end
```

you can also use the [unscoped](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class) method to clear the `default_scope`

```
def index
  if params[:ignored_eq] == 1
    @q = Venue.unscoped.search(params[:q])
  else
    @q = Venue.search(params[:q])
  end
  @venues = @q.result.page(params[:page]).per_page(15)
end
```

which is prettier (IMO)

Comment: Still, this will display all records when I enter the page which is not the desired behaviour. I want to have only the non-ignored records displayed when entering the page and have the checkbox unchecked. Once I check it and submit the form the results should include ignored and non-ignored records.

Comment: @kitsched yes, I edited the answer. But you can get the general idea.

Comment: Tried both versions, when I check the box it only returns the ignored ones. Search overwrites `unscoped` and `rewhere`.

Comment: With your help I got to: http://pastebin.com/YzBU4j2Q - which works correctly except that the checkbox won't "stick" (it always stays unchecked) despite my feeble try on line #4.

Comment: @kitsched `params[:q][:ignored_eq] = nil` is not correct. you need `params[:q].delete :ignored_eq` because a `nil` value key results in a *key = NULL* query.
try using the `to_sql` method to inspect your queries.

Comment: Tried that too, however my checkbox still won't get checked. And since I'm deleting the parameter it doesn't get into the pager. Solution still not found.

Comment: Found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490458/eq-any-for-boolean-attributes-ransack) but still no real solution.